# Azure Blob Storage Server-side encryption (encryption-at-rest) question

Tags: azure, encryption, blob

My question is if the encryption is enabled by default, then why I still can read the file after I downloading it from the portal?  If the decryption is transparent (while I downloading it), then what kind of protection does this encryption provide?  As long as I can download files from the blob, this encryption is useless to me, correct?

I am confuse!  Please help!

Best,

Worrow

Comment: Encryption done by a storage provider protects against a) stolen disks, b) cases where disks are reused without wiping them properly first, c) rogue employees and intruders that have access to the data storage but not key storage.